# can i write to sql database while android mobile getting switched off

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to store some data while the device is shutting down, so that i could use those values
after reboot.

Can i use `android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN`-intent to fullfill my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to store some data while the device is shutting down, so that i could use those values after reboot.

No, you need to store the data when it changes.

Devices do not always shut down cleanly (e.g., battery pops out). Also, the user can terminate your application without warning using a task killer or the Settings application. Please save the data as you go, when it changes, so you do not lose data in these cases. As a side benefit, you will no longer care about the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` event.

Comment: ,Thanks for replying.Actually, i am working on an app based on traffic stats Api ,where on each shutdown, counter set to zero, so before the device shut down, i somehow, need to save earlier data. Then, i think it will be better to use timer to keep data updating.